# LetsEncrypt SSL Certificates with multi domains and multi subdomains

Tags: email, ssl, dns, certificate, lets-encrypt

We've been using a PositiveSSL Multi-Domain Cert for some years, and that's been working fine. Under that Cert, we have, for instance:

domain1:

- `mail.domain1.com`
- `www.domain1.com`
- `domain1.com`

domain2:

- `mail.domain2.fr`
- `www.domain2.fr`
- `domain2.fr`

etc., with a total of 5 different domains.

Now, since we're going to expand our domain base and that the current Cert is expiring, we're looking closely at Lets-Encrypt.

Before I get into this, however, I'd like to know a couple of things:

(1)- does every subdomain (`mail.` `www.`, etc.) as well as their main respective domain have to be listed in the main certificate? I'm mainly asking that because (a) that was my original understanding, and (b) the verification stage with Lets-Encrypt will differ (`preferred-challenges=dns` instead of by default apache-based), which will lead me to add DNS records for each domain/subdomain.

(2)- if it is indeed needed (and if I have no choice but use `preferred-challenges=dns`, at the time of the next Cert renewal (i.e. < 90 days), should the DNS records still have to be present? I'm asking this because last time I left the DNS records after creation, the mail server couldn't be reached anymore after the DNS propagation time. I'm pretty sure that it was because of my bad setup, but it's a risk I prefer to avoid taking.

(3)- if I'm missing here of you have a better advice to give me, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar issue or plan, this is what I've learned during this [process](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ssl-certificates-with-multi-domains-and-multi-subdomains/46379):

- Every domain name that the certificate will be used for has to be included. Let’s Encrypt will validate each of the domain names in the certificate.
- If using DNS-01 validation, all of them will require DNS records to be added. With that, records will be required to re-validate the domains every 90 days (or whatever time frame you choose). This will require adding a new TXT record each time. Leaving the old TXT records from a previous validation will not work, the value changes each time.
- There are also HTTP-01 and TLS-SNI-01 challenge types. If you already have an Apache instance running I recommend using HTTP-01.
- If you don’t have a webserver on the machine that runs mail.domain1.com you can still use HTTP-01. Certbot has a feature called “standalone” mode where it can start up a small purpose built webserver to answer HTTP-01 challenges to provision a certificate.
- To use HTTP or TLS-SNI validation on a non-web server, you would run something like: `certbot certonly --standalone -d mail.example.com`. You still need to have port 80 or 443 open in your firewall to use this method, but you need no server running on those ports. If you only want to open one port you can specify the challenge type explicitly, e.g. `--preferred-challenges http` to use port 80 or `--preferred-challenges tls-sni` to use port 443.

Answer (score 1):

At https://websocket.email I am using the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) mechanism to handle api.websocket.email etc. I did not have to configure DNS records and used http challenges. The exact way you would do this depends on your acme client. Mine had the option listed under a config section "alternative names".

Edit: To clarify, I needed DNS records to point to my subdomains all to the same server, I am using this acme client - https://man.openbsd.org/acme-client.conf.5 and set the alternative names option. When getting my certificates I could see in my http logs, lets-encrypt fetching a single challenge file per domain to prove I own it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Chambers for your input. That has partially answered my question. I've taken it to the Let's Encrypt forum, @ https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ssl-certificates-with-multi-domains-and-multi-subdomains/46379. FYI.